# ruby case when statement on a hash

Tags: ruby

```
MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG = {"Flat/Unit No." => "FLD_ADD_1Line1",
                          "Building No./Name" => "FLD_ADD_2Line2",
                          "Street" => "FLD_ADD_3Line3",
                          "Postcode" => "FLD_ADD_4Postcode",
                          "City/Town" => "FLD_ADD_5City",
                          "Region" => "FLD_ADD_6State",
                          "Suburb" => "FLD_ADD_Town"
}

data_hash = {"Street" => "s", "Suburb" => "sb", "abc" => "hdkhd"}

data_hash.each do |key, value|
  case key
  when  <if key equal to the key of MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG i.e    MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG.has_key?(key)>
    puts 'something'
  when "Mobile"
    puts "something mobile"
  else
    puts 'something else'
  end
end
```

Rather than writing like

when "Flat/Unit No.","Building   No./Name","Street","Postcode","City/Town","Region","Suburb"

Is there any better way to write this?

Comment: I need to do the 'put' statement for all the keys in the data_hash

Answer (score 0):

Like you already wrote:

```
MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG.has_key?(key)
```

Or just:

```
MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG[key]
```

Or (would be slower):

```
MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG.keys.include?(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG.has_key?(key)` will do the thing. And it is best way to do it with the information you've supplied. You have a data source `MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG` and request hash - `data_hash`. You need to check each request to be in data source.

Also as I remember you can delete all `puts` in the `switch` statement and put `puts` before the case.

**But there is one more way.** Leaving a `case-when` statement out. So this may be more elegant.

```
data_hash.each do |key, value|
    # Check if the key is Mobile  (this is non-trivial key)
    puts "something mobile" if key == "Mobile"

    # Simply check if there is data in the hash for the key
    # if yes - the result will be a string and will eveluate to true
    # causing the first string to be printed out. But if there is no 
    # other such key in the hash - you will get nil that will be
    # evaluated to false resulting in the second string to be returned 
    # from expression in curly braces and sequentally to be printed.
  puts ( MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG[key] ?  'something' : 'something else' )
end
```

Comment: It seems not working if I use the option as part of case ..when. Actually I need to use the case when statement only as there are few more options from few other hashes like MAP_PERSONAL_DATA_WITH_TAG which I have not mentioned in the above example.